# ,reading a data file with both strings and numerals and sorting them based on the comparison of the stirngs

Tags: python

I would like to read a .txt file into python. The file contains a time stamp in the form of  a string followed by 10 lines of numbers , followed by a string(timestamp) and 10 line of numbers and so on so forth. Could you help me figure out an optimal way to read the data and sort out the numbers based on the the value of the string, such as if any two strings have the same value then add/subtract the respective data. 
The data is as follows.
'6:30:35 '
   23.3027954
   23.3238354
   23.3380013
   23.3754082
   23.3739243
    '6:30:35 '
   23.2339077
   23.2555122
   23.2627373
   23.3108864
   23.3045197
 '6:26:39 '
   23.6945286
   23.7161140
   23.7225990
   23.7461128
   23.7615738
   23.7875786
  '6:26:39 '
   23.6104450
   23.6228142
   23.6390495
   23.6526394
   23.6695328
   23.7029572

The desired output should be able to add/subtract the values with the same time stamp string. like add the value with time stamps 6:30:35 together for example.

Comment: Add sample input in text format and also show desired output.

Comment: See [ask]. You need to show some code, otherwise SO becomes a code writing service.